# How to process huge array in google function and then download response in csv?

Tags: csv, google-cloud-functions, report

This is for report download.

I'm able to pull out data from db(mongo) using aggregation but after passing data to google function to decrypt some fields creating issue and send csv on mail.

In above system design I'm getting timeout on google function even on max timeout and 1gb memory.

Please help me out where is getting wrong in design.

Comment: Use Cloud Run instead. You can set a 1H timeout and use several CPUs (if your application support multithreading)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.